# "Small question" or "little question"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There could be a question of which the questioner does not know the answer. But the question may be very easy to the answering person because he is very familiar with the issue or has the information at hand.

What should such a question be called—"small," "little," or what?

(Of course, we can call it an easy question. But an easy question is usually easy for all.)

Comment: I think I've usually heard "little question", but not sure why. Maybe *small* makes you think of the size rather than the scope?

Comment: In most academic circles I hear such questions referred to as "trivial questions/examples", or simply "trivial"

Comment: I agree, i wouldn't use either "small" or "little" in this context and would probably use "trivial" instead.

Comment: An "elementary" question is one which a beginner in a particular subject might ask but someone experienced ought to know. Is this what you mean?

Comment: If I were addressing a colleague who specializes in whatever topic I'm investigating, I would ask him if he had time for a "quick question".

Comment: It is more likely to be called a *trivial* question.

Comment: I would have said that whether a question was *trivial* or not depended on the importance to the questioner of having the information, rather than the ease with which it can be answered by the person being asked.

Comment: @HughMeyers — I think "elementary question" is best. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/little) actually gives << **little**: 3: small in importance or interest : TRIVIAL _a few little problems to be dealt with_ >>

Answer (score 1):

**Little** is a very subtle word in English. A **little thing** can sometimes be a very important thing, as when Boromir and Frodo confront each other over the One Ring.

Asking **a little question** or **just one small question** can sometimes be a slight self-deprecation, often used by emotionally-aware leaders https://www.inc.com/anne-gherini/what-a-self-deprecating-sense-of-humor-says-about-your-eq.html

However, it can also be used to signal to an audience that something of importance is at hand. Anyone who enjoyed the detective show *Columbo* would have recognized the writer’s use of this technique. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo

So to answer the OP, it’s fine to use **little question** or **small question** in this context, bearing in mind that the adjectives can sometimes carry a larger meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Small and little mean literally the same thing, and refer to physical size.  Therefore, there is no such thing as a small or little question, unless you’re referring to the physical length of a written question—a question which is 1 cm long as apposed to one which is 10 cm long.  Both small and little in this context are grammatically incorrect.  Instead, these questions are brief or succinct, etc.

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/little): << **little**: 3: small in importance or interest : TRIVIAL
a few little problems to be dealt with >> This is why references are so important on ELU. They help eliminate subjective (and especially inaccurate) answers. // Also, 'A few itchy questions' is not grammatically incorrect, it misuses words. Semantic error, not grammatical / syntactic error.

Answer (score -2):

Small is used when we characterize the size, so this word is not appropriate here. I guess that little is also not very good in this situation. Little is used , when we talk about age. Maybe you should use another grammatical construction, explaining the very situation you are talking about.

Comment: I found that _a quick question_ works in many cases.

Comment: Neither is suitable, to my mind.

Comment: A tiny issue, maybe.

Comment: I would agree with @jera - in idiomatic British English a "quick" question is one that the questioner expects the person being questioned to answer quickly, with very little thought or effort.

Comment: There are no small questions, only small people.

Comment: @Fatimahon — A tiny issue is more likely to be a babe in arms. It is certainly not a question of any sort.

Answer (score -3):

A "**softball**" is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/softball) as

> a question that is very easy to answer

Comment: First, this is argot that would only be understood in the US. Second the sense is surely that the questioner knows the answer not the questioned. He is deliberately feeding an easy question to someone like a politician, interviewee or quiz contestant.